# Can we talk about software for games?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

This is not about mods.

I am programming a software that helps people with a certain game, similar to keybinder and settingsmanager. As a side note, it will be open source.

Is it possible to deploy software in here?

Is it allowed to ask questions related to this software, when it is related to a game? (questions from users, obviously not from me)

This is about third party applications rather then direct mods (compare Warcraft 3 keybinder as a standalone program vs WoW visual/casthelper/xy mod).

This is an example tool for Warcraft 3:

http://warkeys.sourceforge.net/

[image]

**TL;DR** third party software: allowed to talk about + deployment?

Comment: What do you mean by "deployment"?

Comment: basically posting a link to http://sourceforge.net/ or a similar page.

this itself sounds cheap but it could be part of an answer too. `How can i do this? How can i activate that?` and i could post an answer and at the end a link saying `this tool can help u assists without doing much yourself`

but tbh i dont know how stackexchange and gaming in particular reacts to this. this is my first public tool (and its not complex) thats why i am asking^^

Comment: "deployment" either sounds like the software term (go to SO or Game-Dev) or advertising some tool you created, which shouldn't be done here unless it's to fulfill a legitimate need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions about using game-related tools are generally on-topic, as long as they pass all other requirements on this site.

Regarding writing answers which contain a link to the tool - if the tool is relevant to the answer, then yes, you can post a link to it. I would recommend you add a disclosure saying that you are involved with it, though.

As long as it only appears as part of relevant answers, it should be fine. Also please put an explanation around it, e.g. not "you can use this tool for this" but "you can use this tool for this, and here's how: ..."

Comment: sure. will keep that in mind. thank you! Well i thought about your last point. wouldnt it be better to have an tutorial/in depth explanation on the developersite? but posting a little tutorial for a specific setting should be alright i guess.

Comment: @Wandang Just to be clear, [according to the FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) you *must* disclose your affiliation; it's not just Oak's recommendation :P.  A "deployment" in the sense of an announcement about your app or advertising would be treated as spam, but from what I gather you don't intend to do that :)

Comment: @Wandang Yes, a comprehensive tutorial on your own site will probably best; but do leave something here beyond a link. For example: "Oh, you want to transmogrify the gondolate? You can use my tool for that. As you can see in page 3 of the tutorial, it's possible to transmogrify a variety of fusgels, including the gondolate, by pressing 'g' - full instructions in the tutorial".

Comment: @MatthewRead i never questioned the disclosure part ;)

Comment: @Wandang I never said you did ;)

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, we have historically considered questions about various gaming related utility apps such as Steam to be **On Topic**.

I have no idea what you are asking in the remainder of your question.

Comment: added an example application (not my own) for clarification.

Comment: I've also noticed that this extends to questions about stuff like FRAPS and Ventrilo, which IMO are not on topic at all. A gaming framework is one thing, a software which people just happen to use while gaming is another.

Comment: i don't differentiate between programs that are used 99% of times for games/gaming and programs that are only usable for games/gaming. tbh i don't know where you would make a sharp line to allow some programs. take for example overwolf (http://www.overwolf.com/). its an overlay only added to games that utilizes programs like teamspeak/browser/etc.