# Website Questions and the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, allowed-questions, site-faq

Well there's this thing about the website questions. As you may know I started a proposal about the [Closing reason external resources](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/close-reason-external-resource) and there I got redirected to the [Discussion about whether or not those questions are allowed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/where-do-website-questions-fit-in-our-scope) (and the last time this post was active was like 2.5 or 3 years ago).

I started the first discussion because I thought those questions were clearly unwelcome on Arqade but then someone showed me a link to a Topic where it said they are clearly allowed. Still, as someone pointed out in the comments of my request: **almost all of the questions get closed right now**.

I found this really confusing and thus I tried to revive the old discussion while bringing in some of my own input and views on this particular topic.

I think the biggest problem is that you cannot see whether or not these questions are allowed and especially new users won't see it (When I created my SE account I didn't even know that there is something like meta). Also those questions aren't rare...  Pretty much the opposite. I feel like they take in a huge part of the closed quesitons of this website.

So my main issue is that you can't really find informations to website questions. **Make the information available for new users**. I don't really care if it's a Yes, Allowed or a No, Not allowed but I really feel like it's a problem that there is absolutely **nothing** except for this meta post.